# Importing classes and NameError

Tags: python, oop, nameerror

Don't see much point in posting whole of an actual code here, so I'll try my best to generalize my problem.
Function(let it be named x) is defined at the start of the code.
Then the class(which has a method z, and z is eventually calling x) is imported from separate .py file. Object of that class is created. After z is called, I get "global name 'x' is not defined" error.
Then I thought I paste all the code from my .py files in a single file, put def(x) on top of it, and see what happens. Of course, it worked as intended. Don't get what is the problem with previous way(which I'd prefer to stick with), isn't it virtually the same?

Answer (score 2):

Globals are *per module*, and functions look up globals in the module they are defined in.

So a class `Foo` defined in a module named `bar`, that needs access to a function named `spam` will look up that function in it's own namespace, so in module `bar`.

If functions were to look up globals in the module they were imported into, you'd have to repeatedly import all the dependencies of any function you ever wanted to use. This would not be practical.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me, +1. Still, I fail to think of a more practical way to run my program than changing the "bar"(which is kind of a template), or putting everything in one module.

Comment: morris: Modules can import other modules which have things they need in them so there's no need to put everything in one module.

Comment: @morris: Functions are first-class objects too; you can pass in a reference to a function (use the name without calling the function) if you need your API to take an arbitrary function.